# Javascript: Set BackgroundColor of <select> item

Tags: javascript, html, select, internet-explorer-8

The following code works just fine in FF and Chrome, but the setting does not work in IE8 :-(

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeColor(id)
  {
    var selectName = "select" + id;
    var selectElement = document.getElementById(selectName);
    var selectValue = selectElement.value;
    var backColor = '#FFFFFF';
    if(selectValue == 'No')
    {
      backColor = 'lightcoral';
    }
    else
    {
      backColor = 'lightgreen';
    }
    selectElement.style.backgroundColor = backColor;
  }
</script>
</head>
...
<form name="update" action="update.php" method="post">
<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="changeColor(1);" >
  <option>No</option>
  <option selected="selected">Yes</option>
</select>
...
```

In IE8 the dropdown just won't change it's back color. This function itself is called though.

If I do this

```
alert(selectElement.style);
```

I get a valid object in IE8: [object CSSStyleDeclaration]

Comment: Use `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value` to get the current selected value

Answer (score 2):

Paul was completely correct.

I was just about to write that I noticed that the error lies completely elsewere

Instead of using

```
var selectValue = selectElement.value;
```

I now use

```
var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
```

And it works!

Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 2):

Set the `backgroundColor` directly on the `<option>`-elements :

```
for (var i=0;i<selectElement.children.length;i++) {
  selectElement.children[i].style.backgroundColor = backColor;
}
```

see **working** fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4eqx5/**

Comment: update, the fiddle colored the options but didnt color them when a new item was selected - this is corrected now (didnt have wrap in head)

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of CSS properties that are specific to a browser.
Use Jquery to not have those problems.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment

Comment: Why not? The answer is: Use Jquery to not have those problems

Comment: Telling the user to just go and use jQuery does not resolve his problem and is therefore not an answer to his solution. This is however a suitable comment as it is a suggestion or way round his problem. Does that help?

Comment: Yes because I think you resolve a lot of problems using jQuery. That problem and future problems. But yes, I'm not resolving this specific problem.